# Transform first item in array to timestamp

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following problem in the example below

```html
***/*For this object */***
data:{
  "date": "2021-01-25 07:17:00",,
  "open": 0.0096367,
  "low": 0.0096367,
  "high": 0.00963707,
  "close": 0.00963707,
  "volume": 0
}

/*I use this code */

  const keys = ["date", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume"],
            results = {
              ohlcv: Object.entries(data).map(([volume, open]) => [
                ...keys.map((k) => open[k])
              ]),
            };
            
/*To turn it to this array*/

ohlcv: [
          [
            "2021-01-25 07:17:00",
            0.00963206,
            0.00963243,
            0.00963206,
            0.00963206,
            0,
          ],
        ]
```

So far so good but,
how to change the date in the array to timestamp with Date.parse() function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: im trying to replicate it but i get 6 arrays of each length 6 and all full of `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
    "date": "2021-01-25 07:17:00",
    "open": 0.0096367,
    "low": 0.0096367,
    "high": 0.00963707,
    "close": 0.00963707,
    "volume": 0
};

const results = {
    ohlcv: Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
        if (key === 'date') {
            return new Date(value).getTime() / 1000;
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    })
};

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

i just make it work

```html
 results = {
              ohlcv: Object.entries(response.data).map(([volume, open]) => [
                Date.parse(open.date), <-this line
                ...keys.map((k) => open[k]),
              ]),
            };
```